# R: replace identical rows with average

Tags: r

I have data which looks like this:

```
patient day response
Bob "08/08/2011" 5
```

However, sometimes, we have several responses for the same day (from the same patient). For all such rows, I want to replace them all with just one row, where the patient and the day is of course what it happens to be for all those rows, and the response is the average of them.

So if we also had

```
patient day response
Bob "08/08/2011" 6
```

then we'd remove both these rows and replace them with

```
patient day response
Bob "08/08/2011" 5.5
```

How do I write up a code in R to do this for a data frame that spans tens of thousands of rows?

EDIT: I might need the code to generalize to several covariables. So, for example, apart from day, we might have "location", so then we'd only want to average all the rows which correspond to the same patient on the same day on the same location.

Comment: Atleast give a reproducible example. Also, mention what you have tried so far.

Comment: See `?aggregate` for starters

Comment: Neither of the two answers nor the comment would replace values but they all would probably give you useful results.

Answer (score 0):

Required output can be obtained by:

```
 aggregate(a$response, by=list(Category=a$patient,a$date), FUN=mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the dplyr package pretty easily:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(patient, day) %>%
    summarize(response_avg = mean(response))
```

This groups by whatever variables you choose in the `group_by` so you can add more. I named the new variable "response_avg" but you can change that to what you want also.

Answer (score 0):

just to add a data.table solution if any reader is a data.table user.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, response := mean(response, na.rm = T), by = .(patient, day)]
df <- unique(df)   # to remove duplicates
```